# Pandas Join within a join

Tags: pandas, join

I'm trying to join a ranked recommendation dataframe with a dataframe containing true actions for each user (indicating whether they watched the recommended movie or not). I'd like to first join on id column and then join on recommendations/true_actions for that id. Here's an example:

```
rec_df:                                    labels_df:

id | recommendation | rank |               id | movie 1.| movie2.| movie 3|
----------------------------               --------------------------------
110|  movie 1.      | 1.   |               110|  0.     |   1    |  0
110|  movie 2.      | 2.   |               --------------------------------
110|  movie 3       | 3.   |               210|  1.     |   0    |  1
----------------------------               --------------------------------
210|  movie 1.      | 2.   |
210|  movie 2.      | 1.   |
210|  movie 3       | 3.   |
----------------------------

the desired resulting df after join:

id | recommendation | rank | true_action             
----------------------------------------               
110|  movie 1.      | 1.   |     0      |    
110|  movie 2.      | 2.   |     1      |   
110|  movie 3       | 3.   |     0      |   
----------------------------------------               
210|  movie 1.      | 2.   |     1      |
210|  movie 2.      | 1.   |     0      |
210|  movie 3       | 3.   |     1      |
----------------------------
```

Is there an easy way to do this type of join in pandas? thanks a lot for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just flatten `labels_df` before joining:

```
df1['true_action'] = df1.merge(df2.melt('id', var_name='recommendation'), 
                               on=['id', 'recommendation'], how='left')['value']
print(df1)

# Output
    id recommendation  rank  true_action
0  110        movie 1     1            0
1  110        movie 2     2            1
2  110        movie 3     3            0
3  210        movie 1     2            1
4  210        movie 2     1            0
5  210        movie 3     3            1
```

*Note: I remove all trailing dots to be clearer*